# Install DBI-mysql for Perl 5.18.xx

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

I am using perl 5.18.1.1800 with ppm 4.19 in a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

I need to use DBD-mysql to be able to access mysql from perl. But I get below error message:

```
use DBI();
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=mydbname;host=localhost","myuser", "mypass",{'RaiseError' => 1})
```

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you
>   may need to install the DBD::mysql module)

So i tried to install DBD-mysql, but i don't have that listed in my PPM. In command line, when I tried to install, i get below error

```
ppm install DBD-mysql
```

> ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides DBD-mysql

I tried to download and install it, but it requires a C compiler which I don't have.

From [DBD-mysql info page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/), there is no mentioning of Perl 5.18 support for the module.

So, should I revert back to 5.16.xx or the problem is something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBD-mysql is available for ActivePerl-5.16.3.1604. Reverting back to that version is probably simpler than installing a compiler to build the package yourself.

Activestate used Visual Studio to build DBD-mysql: http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.16/1600/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.022.d/log-20120830T032945.txt

[image]

```
C:\>ppm install DBD-mysql
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...done
Updating ActiveState Package Repository database...done
Syncing site PPM database with .packlists...done
Downloading DBD-mysql-4.022...done
Unpacking DBD-mysql-4.022...done
Generating HTML for DBD-mysql-4.022...done
Updating files in site area...done
  12 files installed
```

Comment: Running `C:\>ppm install DBD-mysql` in command prompt worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the module is DBI. Try using:

```
ppm install DBI
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't used Perl on Windows, rather Perl on Linux, so I assumed the syntax for using ppm is "ppm install modulename".

also, the correct syntax hereafter would be:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(DBI:mysql:DBNAME, $username, $pass, {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit 
=> 1}) or die "Could not Connect to DB";
```